# find_each Active Record Querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this method in my model to allow my view to display all equipment associated with a vehicle. Should I be using find_each to check batches of records, and if so, how would I break this method down to use it?

```
def equip(vehicle)
  equip = Vehicle.find_by_id(vehicle).equipments.
        where("vehicle_id = ?", vehicle).all
end
```

Comment: is `vehicle` the id of a vehicle?

Comment: @Deekor - yes, I'm passing in the vehicle.id when I call the method from the view.  It looks through the equipment table and finds all the equipment assigned to a given vehicle.

Comment: The answer below should suffice. Just a side note you should be able to just call `Vehicle.find(vehicle)..` rather than `find_by_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use .all at the end, it will trigger the query when its called and will be a pain as perfomances.

Also, you should use this syntax (Rails 3):

```
def equip(vehicle)
  equip = Equipment.where(vehicle_id: vehicle.try(:id) || vehicle)
end
```

Using this, you only use the Equipment model, which will just use the `equipments` SQL table (not 2 or more).

```
# This line
vehicle.try(:id) || vehicle
# Allows you to pass both a Vehicle object or a vehicle id to your method
```

Also, if you have already an instance of vehicle, you could use:

```
def equip(vehicle)
  equip = Vehicle.where(id: vehicle).first.equipments
  # or with your syntax:
  equip = Vehicle.find(vehicle).equipments
end
```

Comment: Implemented it, but got undefined method id. When I took out the vehicle.try(:id) it worked fine.  Also, should I consider find_each? My understanding of it right now is that this would load the entire equipment table into memory first, then start processing